# Как правильно сравнивать pointer и integer?

Tags: c++builder

Следующая ошибка:

`[bcc32c Error] bcbl.cpp(47): comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *')`

Код:

```
String str = "text,text";
if (str[5] == ",")  // ошибка
```

в чем я неправ и как правильно сравнивать?

Comment: `str[5] == ','` ну это же азы Си и описано в каждом первом учебнике/туториале про различие символов и строк

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно сравнивать `char`.

```
String str = "text,text";
if (str[5] == ',')
```

Причина такова:

Вот это `str[5]` == `char`, а вот это `","` == `const char*`, но `','` == `char`.

Comment: О, помогло! Спс!